# Plane displacement using a height map is not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, heightmap

The heightmap I want to use:

[image: heightmap]

Scene without grass.jpg map :

[image: scene]

Scene with grass.jpg map:

[image]

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import * as dat from 'dat.gui';

// dimensions of the plane x, y
const planeDim = new THREE.Vector2(20, 20);
const planeSeg = new THREE.Vector2(100, 100);

// Cam start coordinates x, y, z
let camPos = new THREE.Vector3(-10, 30, 30);

// Cam settings
const camFOV = 45;
const camAspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
let camNear = 0.1;
let camFar = 1000;

// AxesHelper size
let axesHelperSize = 5;

// Gridhelper dimensions x, y
const gridHelperDim = new THREE.Vector2(20, 20);

// Mouseover highligthed tile starting coordinates x, y, z
let tilePos = new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0, 0.5);

// Mouseover highlighted tile dimensions x, y
const tileDim = new THREE.Vector2(1, 1);


// Creating variables to work with raycasting from mouseposition
const mousePosition = new THREE.Vector2();
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
let intersects;

// Array of all sphere objects placed on the plane
const objects = [];

//creating the renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// enable shadows in the scene
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Creating the Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Creating the camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    camFOV,
    camAspect,
    camNear,
    camFar
);

// Declaring the Camera as an OrbitCamera
const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
camera.position.set(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z);
orbit.update();

// creating and adding the AxesHelper to the scene
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(axesHelperSize);
scene.add(axesHelper);


// Loading the heightmap-texture
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const displacementMap = loader.load('res/heightmap.jpg');
const map = loader.load('res/grass.jpg');

// creating the plane with displacement
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeDim.x, planeDim.y, planeSeg.x, planeSeg.y),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    visible: true,
    displacementMap: displacementMap,
    displacementScale: 20,
    map: map,
    flatShading: false
  })
);
// enable recieving shadows on the plane
planeMesh.receiveShadow = true;

// giving the plane a name
planeMesh.name = 'ground';
// adding the plane to the scene
scene.add(planeMesh);
// rotate the plane 90 degrees
planeMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

// creating the gridHelper on the plane
const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(gridHelperDim.x, gridHelperDim.y);
// adding the gridhelper into the scene
scene.add(gridHelper);

// creating the highlighted tile, setting its position and adding it to the scene
const highlightMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(tileDim.x, tileDim.y),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00FF00,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true
  })
);
highlightMesh.position.set(tilePos.x, tilePos.y, tilePos.z);
highlightMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(highlightMesh);

// raycasting function. Tile on mouseposition will be highlighted
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  mousePosition.x = (e.clientX / this.window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mousePosition.y = -(e.clientY / this.window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mousePosition, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  intersects.forEach(function(intersect){
    if(intersect.object.name === 'ground'){
      const highlightPos = new THREE.Vector3().copy(intersect.point).floor().addScalar(0.5);
      highlightMesh.position.set(highlightPos.x, 0, highlightPos.z);
    
      // returns true if tilespace is already used
      const objectExists = objects.find(function(object){
        return (object.position.x === highlightMesh.position.x)
        && (object.position.z === highlightMesh.position.z);
      });

      // changes tile color to white if tile is empty and red if not
      if(!objectExists){
        highlightMesh.material.color.setHex(0x00FF00);
      }else{
        highlightMesh.material.color.setHex(0xFF0000);
      }
    }
  });
});

// Creating the sphere object
const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.4, 4, 2),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    wireframe: true,
    color: 0xAEAEDB
  })
);
// enabling sphere to cast a shadow
sphereMesh.castShadow = true;

// Click event, clicking tile will spawn the sphere object on it
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
  // returns true if the clicked tile already has a sphere
  const objectExists = objects.find(function(object){
    return (object.position.x === highlightMesh.position.x)
    && (object.position.z === highlightMesh.position.z);
  })

  // if tile is empty, spawn a shpere, else - console log
  if(!objectExists){
    intersects.forEach(function(intersect){
      if(intersect.object.name === 'ground'){
        const sphereClone = sphereMesh.clone();
        sphereClone.position.copy(highlightMesh.position);
        scene.add(sphereClone);
        objects.push(sphereClone);
        //make tile red instantly after clicking to indicate the tile space is already in use
        highlightMesh.material.color.setHex(0xFF0000);
      }
    }) 
  }else{
    console.log('Can not place, space is already used!')
  }
});


// adding ambient light to the scene
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// adding a spotlight to the scene
const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(spotLight);
spotLight.position.set(-100, 100, 0);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.angle = 0.2;
// ading a lighthelper to help see the light settings
const sLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(spotLight);
scene.add(sLightHelper);


// creating the light gui itself
const gui = new dat.GUI();

// adding options to dat.gui to change seetings of the light and plane
const options = {
  angle: 0.2,
  penumbra: 0,
  intensity: 1,
  wireframe: false
};
// creating the light gui settings and setting its boundries
gui.add(options, 'angle', 0, 1);
gui.add(options, 'penumbra', 0, 1);
gui.add(options, 'intensity', 0, 1);

// enables wireframemode for the plane
gui.add(options, 'wireframe').onChange(function(e){
  planeMesh.material.wireframe = e;
});

// animation loop with time parameter
function animate(time){
  // bind the gui options to the spotlight
  spotLight.angle = options.angle;
  spotLight.penumbra = options.penumbra;
  spotLight.intensity = options.intensity;
  // bind the gui options to the plane
  planeMesh.wireframe = options.wireframe;
  // update lighthelper appearence according to the settings
  sLightHelper.update();
  // make the tile blinking
  highlightMesh.material.opacity = 1 + Math.sin(time / 120);
  // rotation animation on every sphere object on the plane
  objects.forEach(function(object){
    object.rotation.x = time / 500;
    object.rotation.y = time / 500;
    object.position.y = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.abs(Math.sin(time / 1000));
  })
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

// logging in the browser console
console.log();
```

My approach to displacements using height maps doesn't work. I want to generate a plane with a displaced surface, but the plane stays flat and white, or turns black.

I tried to change the path of the heightmap.jpg. I also tried different ThreeJS materials. I tried to use flatshading in the planeMesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add the image as texture correctly you will need to import the image first

```
import image from "./j1wxR.jpg";
```

then you need to load the image with the texture loader :

```
// Loading the heightmap-texture
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const displacementMap = loader.load(image);
```

To be able to apply the texture on the material and to use "displacementMap", you will need to use both `map` and `displacementMap`  (in your case you need to load the grass texture the same way - and add it to map)

```
// creating the plane with displacement
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeDim.x, planeDim.y, planeSeg.x, planeSeg.y),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    displacementMap: displacementMap,
    map: displacementMap,
    displacementScale: 5
  })
);
```

Notice: I made the `displacementScale` to be 5, just so you can see the difference.

here is a link to codesandbox with a live example:
[Codesandbox - example](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-lake-1frobm?file=/src/index.js)

Probably next you will need to figure out how to make the grid helper be on top of the mesh, and how to place the spheres (with y position) according to the mesh. (but for that, you will need to create another question).

Comment: If you remove the `map`, you will see the terrain renders white -- without proper shading. That is because the normals are not updated.

Comment: @WestLangley Can you please explain more about it? and maybe give a suggestion? i tried to test it with ```.computeVertexNormals()``` and with ```needUpdate = true``` but seems like it doesnt work. im asking for my knowledge and to improve the answer. thank you very much

Comment: Vertices are only displaced on the GPU -- not the CPU. The actual surface remains flat, and the normals remain perpendicular to each face. You need to do _one_ of the following: (1) add a normal map consistent with the displacement map, (2) update the normals in the vertex shader in addition to the vertex positions (not easy), (3) set `material.flatShading`, which will result in a faceted surface, (4) modify the vertices on the CPU and call `geometry..computeVertexNormals()`.